# find docs with same fields in different time intervals in Elastic

Tags: database, elasticsearch, date-range

I have a big dataset in Elasticsearch and I'm trying to find a way to check if one doc from the last 14 days also exist with similar fields (four fields must be the same) in the last 15-90 days.

So I have two time intervals and I would like to check if there are similar one in them.